# What's wrong with my TypeScript/JavaScript discord.js code

Tags: javascript, discord

This is my code and I need a way to fix it. This code is supposed to make my bot change statuses every 10 minutes but instead, it just makes my bot have no status at all.

What's wrong with my code?

[image]

```
client.on('ready', () =>{
    console.log(`up n runnin wOof!`); setInterval(() => client.user.setPresence({
      status: "online",
      game: {
          name: (arrayRandom(actvs)),
          type: "WATCHING" }
        }
    ), 1000 * 60 * 10);

  });
```

Comment: According to the [Discord API docs](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/gateway#activity-object), `"WATCHING"` is not a valid type.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol, actually, "WATCHING" is a valid type and I've used it [right here](https://cdn.glitch.com/96d8736b-f6f7-4bfb-9dc1-7c12a3155077%2F3db9f944-e09b-41f3-b4dc-2b8c8f14e965.image.png?v=1591454367442)

Comment: Have you tried to remove the parentheses around your `arrayRandom` function ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to wait 10 minutes ?

When launching an interval, the code will be executed when the timer stops, which, in your case, would be 10 minutes after launching it.